# Opcache does not get enabled

Tags: php, apache2, opcache

I've installed Apache 2.4.x webserver on Ubuntu and also PHP5.5.x from sources. I go to php installation folder and do `find . -name "opcache.so"`. Then, to php.ini (same as in phpinfo()), I add `zend_extension=/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-x/opcache.so`, and `opcache.enable=On (or 1)` and restart Apache with `apachectl restart`. Then I check phpinfo() but opcache does not get enabled! Please help.

I think a wrong php.ini file might be used, but in phpinfo() it shows the path to file which I do edit. When I change maximum upload filesize from 2M to 4M in the php.ini, and restart Apache, it does not get changed in phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, after compilation PHP would look for the ini file in /usr/local/lib rather than where I installed it despite

```
 --with-config-file-path=PATH
Set the path in which to look for php.ini [PREFIX/lib]
```

To check it, you can run php --ini to see if the file has been read fine. 
But now I'm seeing white screen when trying to load php files :)

Hope it helps.